# C# .NET - detect if code is running as a hangfire job

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, hangfire

Is it possible to detect if code is running as a hangfire job in C#?
Thank you

I would expect that some global system variable exists and indicates code is running as a part of hangfire job.

Comment: _"I would expect that some global system variable exists"_ - why would you expect that?

Comment: U can use a static variable that u can setup from the hangfire job if the u have the same  AppDomain.

Comment: Why not pass this piece of information directly to your job, or for more advanced scenarios, pass whatever behavior that needs to change based on whether it's running as a job or not in the form of delegates or interfaces with an alternate implementation?

Comment: You could add the parameter `PerformContext context = null` as a parameter to your method. If your method is being called from Hangfire the parameter won't be null. The only other approach that comes to my mind would be to inspect the `StackTrace` to find out who called the method.

Comment: Let me guess: You have a piece of code that is called both directly and via hangfire, and, somewhere, deep down the call stack, you want to do something differently, right? I know that it's tempting to just pass the state in some ExecutionContext-local variable, and it might even be justified in edge cases. However, before doing that, consider a "clean" solution that involves restructuring your code and introducing some "inversion of control" pattern.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. @Heinzi You guessed exactly what I need. So you mean I have refactor the code to avoid the calls via HF and via Http?

Comment: @honneq: If that's possible, that would probably be the cleanest solution. That might also make it easier for you to unit-test your code.

Answer (score 1):

> I would expect that some global system variable exists and indicates
> code is running as a part of hangfire job.

I would be curious about your usecase. Having code depending explicitly on the execution context is more difficult to maintain and test in my opinion.
Is it because your code depends on HttpContext, which is not available when running the task with Hangfire ?

Anyway, you could achieve what you want with AsyncLocal and Hangfire ServerFilters

```
public static class HangfireTaskMonitor
{
    public static AsyncLocal<bool> IsRunningInBackground { get; } = new AsyncLocal<bool>();
}

public class ContextTrackedAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IServerFilter
{
    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
    {
      HangfireTaskMonitor.IsRunningInBackground.Value = true;
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
    {
      HangfireTaskMonitor.IsRunningInBackground.Value = false;
    }
}
```

Then put the `[ContextTracked]` attribute on your job method and test `HangfireTaskMonitor.IsRunningInBackground.Value` whenever you want.

The idea is somewhat simplified for clarity. For a more decoupled solution, I would  have the HangfireTaskMonitor being injected as a singleton instead of a static class ; have the filter be a simple filter declared upon Hangfire configuration, instead of being  an attribute.

Comment: Yes, the code depends on HttpContext. I will try AsyncLocal and Hangfire ServerFilters as you mentioned., it looks fine :) Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can register Scoped instances and initialize them using a similar example I explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77201586/13845498

In your case just inject the scoped instance in your Hook, initialize it with some values like the JobId and then inject that instance in your classes. You can check the JobId value to be sure it is running in a Hangfire scope.